# SQL Server : computing percentage from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I'm creating a solution that will compute the percentage of students in a particular bmi status by grade level. I have made a table student_info where students are stored, and multiple tables g1, g2, g3, g4, g5, g6, and kinder where bmi stats of the students are stored. I have tried

```
SELECT 
    si.grade AS 'Grade Level', g4.fstat AS 'Status',
    (SELECT COUNT(si.lrn) * 100.0 / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM student_info)) AS 'Total'
FROM 
    student_info AS si, g4
GROUP BY
    g4.fstat, si.grade
```

I'm only getting the results out of g4 table, but I want to join all 7 tables to compute them all in all. Appreciate the help

Comment: The question is unclear to me. Can you share the tables' structures, some sample data and the result you're trying to get for this sample?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and your query is invalid standard SQL). Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: Do those `g` tables have a field or fields to join them on the student_info table? F.e. something like `student_id`?

Comment: yes they all have lrn which is primary key to student_info

Answer (score 0):

You're only getting the results for the `g4` table because that's the only one that's in your select.  Assuming you have the same table structure in each of your grade levels, and there are no students in more than one grade level, I would start by unioning them together, like so:

```
Select 'K' as grade, * from kinder
union all
Select '1' as grade, * from g1
union all
Select '2' as grade, * from g2
```

.... etc for the rest of your tables.

Then use the results of that union (as a table or temp table, or as a CTE) instead of just table `g4` in the query you have.

Answer (score 0):

You want to join all 7 tables but where are your joins? You're grouping by g4.fstat  and si.grade but I don't see any other code that would pull anything from your other tables. You need to join all your tables on their common fields and add those joined fields to your select if you want to see results.